# Exception in Thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/ssl/SSlContextBuilder running Selenium / Java file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, netty

I have basic 4 line code where I'm setting chromedriver exe system property and instantiated Chromedriver. But, failed with error "Exception in Thread 'main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/ssl/SSLContextBuilder

```
import org.openqa.selenium.webDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class SelPractice {
public static void main(String[] args)
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Timer

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient( NettyClient.java:135 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>( HttpCommandExecutor.java:107 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>( HttpCommandExecutor.java:94 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>( HttpCommandExecutor.java:85 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>( DriverCommandExecutor.java:80 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>( ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:35 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>( ChromeDriver.java:94 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>( ChromeDriver.java:82 )

   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>( ChromeDriver.java:50 )

   at SelPractice.main( SelPractice.java:11 )

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : io.netty.util.Timer

   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

   ... 10 more
```

Comment: what is that second bracket doing there at the end of the code?

Comment: One for the Class and the other for the main method @RolandasUlevicius

Answer (score 0):

You muss to add the dependency which contains this class. If you use maven, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom. If not download the jar and add it to your classpath

Comment: I did that but not got new error  -  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : "io.netty.handler.ssl.sslcontext.newclientcontextInternal"

Comment: Looks like the version is incompatible with other jars in your project. Which netty version do you use?

Comment: I have used Netty 5.0.0.Alpha version

Comment: Than use the same version for the handler. Have changed my answer

Comment: I have used same version of Netty - "netty-all-4.1.91" and netty-handler-4.1.91" but getting error - Exception in thread "main" java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError:  io/netty/util/Timer

Comment: You must have some other incompatible ibraries in your classpath

Comment: I have  - Failsafe 3.3.1 ; guava 31.0.1-jre ; netty-all-4.1.91.final ; netty-handler-4.1.91.final ; selenium-api-4.8.0 ; selenium-chrome-driver-4.8.0 ; selenium-chromium-driver-4.8.0 ; selenium-http-4.8.0 ; selenium-java-4.8.0 ; selenium-manager-4.8.0 ; selenium-remote-driver-4.8.0 ; selenium-support-4.8.0 jar files

Comment: Please add the complete stactrace and the dependency you use to your question

Comment: It's not Maven project, i have added Jars to my classpath

Comment: Please add it to your question. Not as comment

Comment: Added in my question @Jens

Comment: Can someone suggest where i'm doing wrong!